# Restrict each client to one session per user?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, windows-10

I would like to restrict each client to one session per user.

Currently I have group policy set to allow for an unlimited number of sessions per user however I cannot set group policy, as far as I know, to restrict each client to one session per user **AND** allow for an unlimited number of clients per user.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

> to restrict each client to one session per user AND allow for an unlimited number of clients per user.

I'm not quite catching the question, because what you are saying IS how it works.  If you set RDSH to `Restrict each user to a single session = Yes` then the user can establish an RDS session from any client machine/device they want and then disconnect and re-establish it from any other client machine/device they want.

Example:

- I connect from my work laptop to an RDSH session
- I disconnect
- I then reconnect from my home computer

That works by design.